# What are * and / in Bash?

Tags: bash, syntax

I was trying to understand the following code `ls -d */` and came to the explanation that [`*/` "matches all of the subdirectories in the current directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14352330/14993756). But that answer points out, what this does. But my question is, what are these signs called, and how do they work?

As far as I know, I can tell that `/` means a root, but it can also represent some nodes in the directory tree. Is that correct? What about an asterisk?

Comment: From the fine manual: [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)

Comment: `*` (asterisk) is used as the "match anything" symbol in shell patterns / globs, and `/` (slash) is the directory separator, but in general don't for a second think some special character would only have _one_ special meaning in a language as varied as the shell. (esp. if you count all the standard or usual command line tools too.) Not that those two have too many meanings that would be hard to mix up, but anyway.

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the title of your question, you ask about `*` and `/`. In the body of your question, you ask about `*/`. Which is it?

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Comment: @ilkkachu Isn't better to tell that / is a file separator? Because it could also separate files from its directory?

Comment: @GillesQuénot well, I don't know. I am studying globs at the moment and I still haven't come to the answer why `*/` would have to behave how it behaves.

Comment: @Juandev, better for/than what? It knows it's the separator in contexts where it matters and it can do something about it, mostly globbing and tab completion come to mind.

Comment: @Juandev, "why */ would have to behave how it behaves", but that's not what you asked the first time is it? You asked, far more generally, _"what are these signs called, and how do they work?"_ It helps to ask what you want to ask.

Comment: Then, what else should `*/` do? Would there be another useful interpretation? Should it work the same as `*`, just ignoring the `/`? What happens if you create a file called `file1.txt` and try `cat file1.txt/`? Or if you create directory `dir1` and try `cd dir1/` or `rmdir dir1/`? Does it match the behaviour of `*/` in a glob?

Answer (score 3):

`*` it's simply a glob.

`*/` is a hacky glob that match anything followed by `/` (sub directory) aka simple way to find all sub directory with *built-in* code.

Globs are shell patterns that can be used for matching strings or expanding pathnames:
`[[ $name = Bob* ]]`
`rm -- *.txt`
`printf '%s\n' */`

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: The logic behind that "hacky glob" seems to me to be vice versa. Why is that? Glob `*.txt` gives `whatever.txt`, glob `image*` gives `imagewhatever`. So if I am in `workdir` directory and the path is `.../workdir/.. ` I would assume that the right call would be `/*`, so that this glob would list all files within `workdir` directory and if I want only directories, I would use `-d` attribute. But if the glob stands vice versa (i.e. `*/`) I would say it should list the names of files before `workdir` directory.

Comment: @Juandev you are mixing up `ls` (list files and directories) with `*`. The pattern `/*` would match all files and directories in the root directory (`/`). Note that if you do `ls -d /*` then the `ls` command _does not see_ the `/*` pattern - the shell has _already_ replaced it with the set of matching files and directories as a space-separated list before executing `ls`